# d3 to create paths based on separate array of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create svg paths with `d3` and trying to understand how can I ask `d3` to create paths based on separate data.

For example, here I have fixed data for **`path Value`** and two separate sets as **`index1 and index2`**. I want to create paths based on these, meaning I want to create **11** paths altogether, whereas the code below creates only **8** paths.

```js
const width = 1280;
height = 720;

svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

rect = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', `#EFEFEF`)

//src
dataHorizontal = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1280, y: 0 }
];

pathVal = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    (dataHorizontal);

index1 = [1, 2, 3];

index2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

multiplier = 60;

//based on index1

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(index1)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', (d) => `ln${d}`)
    .attr('d', pathVal)
    .attr('stroke', () => { return `hsla(${Math.random() * 360} , ${((Math.random() + Math.random()/2)*100).toFixed(2)}%, 50%, 1)`; })
    .style('transform', (d, i) => { return `translateY(${d*multiplier}px)` })
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
   


//based on index2

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(index2)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', (d) => `ln${d}`)
    .attr('d', pathVal)
    .attr('stroke', () => { return `hsla(${Math.random() * 360} , ${((Math.random() + Math.random()/2)*100).toFixed(2)}%, 50%, 1)`; })
    .style('transform', (d, i) => { return `translateY(${d*multiplier}px)` })
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>    
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg>
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script src="prod.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My best guess is, `d3` is probably overwriting the first 3 paths from `index1` when it starts working on `path2` as the first 3 paths were already available in the DOM.

How can I ask `d3` to ignore the first 3 paths that are available in the DOM and start from scratch for `index2`? I don't want to combine index1 and index 2. What is a d3 way to reach the desired output?

I know I can do this, but is this the only way?

```js
const width = 1280;
height = 720;

svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

rect = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', `#EFEFEF`)

//src
dataHorizontal = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1280, y: 0 }
];

pathVal = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    (dataHorizontal);

index1 = [1, 2, 3];

index2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

multiplier = 60;

//based on index1

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(index1)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', (d) => `ln${d}`)
    .attr('d', pathVal)
    .attr('stroke', () => { return `hsla(${Math.random() * 360} , ${((Math.random() + Math.random()/2)*100).toFixed(2)}%, 50%, 1)`; })
    .style('transform', (d, i) => { return `translateY(${d*multiplier}px)` })
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
   


//based on index2
index2.forEach(
    (a) => {
        svg.append('path')
            .attr('class', () => `ln${a}`)
            .attr('d', pathVal)
            .attr('stroke', () => { return `hsla(${Math.random() * 360} , ${((Math.random() + Math.random()/2)*100).toFixed(2)}%, 50%, 1)`; })
            .style('transform', () => { return `translateY(${a*multiplier}px)` })
            .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    }
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>    
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg>
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script src="prod.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important for you to understand what does selection.join() mean in d3.
Read this post: https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join

It is explained well in above post-**If the joining selection isn’t empty—as on subsequent iterations of the loop above— selection.join appends entering elements and removes exiting elements to match the data!**

You pass index1 as data and when you pass index2 as another set of data, join will remove the exiting elements. And only for entering elements, it will create a path.
In case you want to create lines for both index1 and index2, combine the data and draw with join.

```js
const width = 1280;
height = 720;

svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

rect = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', `#EFEFEF`)

//src
dataHorizontal = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1280, y: 0 }
];

pathVal = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    (dataHorizontal);

index1 = [1, 2, 3];

index2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

multiplier = 60;



//based on index2

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data([...index1,...index2])
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', (d) => `ln${d}`)
    .attr('d', pathVal)
    .attr('stroke', () => { return `hsla(${Math.random() * 360} , ${((Math.random() + Math.random()/2)*100).toFixed(2)}%, 50%, 1)`; })
    .style('transform', (d, i) => { return `translateY(${d*multiplier}px)` })
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>    
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg>
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script src="prod.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An [alternative approach](https://observablehq.com/d/fd759b98bebb1a5a)

Comment: Right, that is a good alternative approach. Thanks for sharing